# Why is the neo4j query plan without cartesian product operation slower?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, profiling, graph-databases, cartesian-product

I am trying to profile a query in Neo4j Cypher.

I started from this query:

```
PROFILE MATCH (t1:Trip{Direction:1, Route:"01"}),(t2:Trip{Direction:0, Route:"01"})
WITH t1, t2 LIMIT 1
MATCH p4 = (t2)−[:STARTS|STOPS|ENDS]−>(:BusStop), p3=(t1)−[:STARTS|STOPS|ENDS]−(:BusStop)
RETURN p3, p4;
```

and I get the following execution plan:

[image]

with a total db hits of 10. The profiling of the query quite fast.

In [this webinar](https://neo4j.com/blog/tuning-cypher-queries/?_ga=2.103674176.1778282353.1562582886-844942336.1528206011) at the 32 minute, it suggests to avoid Cartesian Product operations. According to this I transformed the query to the following:

```
PROFILE MATCH (t1:Trip{Direction:1, Route:"01"})
WITH t1 LIMIT 1
MATCH (t2:Trip{Direction:0, Route:"01"})
WITH t1, t2 LIMIT 1
RETURN t1, t2;
```

resulting in this execution plan:

[image]

with a total db hits of 11: it increased.

Now the profiling shows that the Cartesian product disappeared however the execution seems much slower and the db hits increased.

Why is it slower although the Cartesian product disappeared?
Which query is the better: the one without Cartesian product or the one with fewer db hits? How can I improve my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cartesian products are not always bad. They CAN be bad if you do not intend to create a cartesian product (like `MATCH (p:Person), (m:Movie)`, which gives you the cartesian product of all persons x all movies).

But when you're matching to only a couple nodes, or as in your case, doing lookups of two nodes where you only expect there to be only one of each, it's a perfectly correct thing to do.

So it's all about intention and whether or not the outcome (that it's a cartesian product) comes as a surprise. A cartesian product of 1 x 1 = 1, so that's nothing to be afraid of.

Comment: Ignore estimated rows, those won't help you much. Those are like ballpark figures for the planner, and it deals with very wide orders of magnitude for estimates. Instead look at the actual rows in the PROFILE between the operators.